# Tab space removal using strtok function

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am trying to split a line using strtok which has tab delimiter.My code and input is as below. I would like to store these tokens into field1,field2,field3.

Code:

```
while(fgets(line,80,fp1)!=NULL) //Reading each line from file to calculate the file size.
{
    field1=strtok(line," ");
    //field1=strtok(NULL,"");
    field2=strtok(NULL," ");
    field3=strtok(NULL," ");
    if(flag != 0)
    printf("%s",field1);
    flag++;
}
```

Input:

```
315     316     0.013
315     317     0.022
316     317     0.028
316     318     0.113
316     319     0.133
318     319     0.051
320     324     0.054
321     322     0.054
```

My current output:(If I print field1)

```
315     316     0.013
315     317     0.022
316     317     0.028
316     318     0.113
316     319     0.133
318     319     0.051
320     324     0.054
321     322     0.054
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest just using sscanf.  It handles tabs as delimiters for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
    char line[80], field1[32], field2[32], field3[32];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("testfile", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Could not open testfile\n");
            exit(0);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
            sscanf(line, "%s%s%s", field1, field2, field3);
            printf("%s %s %s\n", field1, field2, field3);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: To avoid potential buffer overflows, you should either define `field1` and friends with the same size as `line` or pass length specifiers this way: `sscanf(line, "%31s%31s%31s", field1, field2, field3);`.  You should also check the return value of `sscanf()` to avoid passing uninitialized data to `printf()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(fgets(line,80,fp1)!=NULL) //Reading each line from file to calculate the file size.
{
    char *p;

    p = strtok(line, '\t');
    int itr = 0;
    while(p != NULL) {
        if(itr == 0){  
           strcpy(field1, p);
           itr++;
        }  
        else if(itr == 1){
           strcpy(field2, p);
           itr++;
        }
        else {
           strcpy(field3, p); 
           itr = 0;
        }
    p = strtok(NULL, '\t');
    }
    printf("%s%s%s", field1, field2, field3);
    // store it in array if needed         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the information here:

```
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/
```

you specified space as the delimiter to use as tokenizer, but your string doesn't have spaces (it seems like tabs to me). So, what strtok does is it starts at the beginning and looks for tab("\t"). It goes until the end of the string and doesn't find it, but it does find \0 which is at the end, so it returns the string at the start since strtok always gives the string before the token to be found.

Change the delimiter to "\t" and then print each field variable.